# How to copy a folder from local mac to linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, amazon-web-services

Im trying to copy the files in htdocs from my mac to a remote server from AWS. How can I do this?

Comment: More info needed. USB Flash? FTP? A dozen other ways.

Comment: I'm not sure a USB drive would work for AWS.

Comment: Could you please add what you have tried to achieve this to better help you with your Answer please.

Answer (score 0):

scp -r -i your_key.pem your_local_folder user@your_ec2_piblic_ip_address:/var/www/htdocs

-r: for recursive
-i: for your ssh key file